# Apache kafka schema-registry issue

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using apache kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0 version, There is a requirement to connect with Salesforce platform to pull the data to our kafka. So i was thinking to install a connector and try to pull the data but i faced few issues and connector itself for salesforce is very old. So other way salesforce team can push the data but need to implement schema registry according to requirement.

So if anyone have any inputs regarding

1. salesforce to apache kafka (not confluent) connector
2. how to implement schema registry for apache kafka?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd strongly recommend upgrading your Kafka version. The Connect APIs have matured well beyond the support for Kafka 0.9. In fact, I don't think it'll work below Kafka 0.10.2, at a minimum (haven't tried, so YMMV).

Connectors can be written on your own by wrapping the [Salesforce API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/api_streaming_code_examples.htm) with the [Connect API](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/devguide.html). You don't need to "find" one.

For a Schema Registry, there are multiple that exist, such as Apicurio, which RedHat maintains, but having a Registry  is not a requirement to use with Kafka Connect.